# Do browsers use resource hint (Link) headers in redirect responses?

Tags: http-headers, web-performance

## The problem

I have a site, that uses a 302 redirect for new visitors to establish a new session. I've created a demo of the basic flow on my personal site:

1. https://crenshaw.dev/redirect/index.php (302)
2. https://crenshaw.dev/session/redirect/index.html (200)

index.html uses resource `https://mac9416.com/demos/style.css` (I just needed an external domain name).

I want to instruct the browser to connect to mac9416.com in the 302 rather than the 200.

## Potential solution

Some browsers support resource hint headers. Here are some examples:

> EXAMPLE 5
>
> Link: https://widget.com; rel=dns-prefetch
>   Link: https://example.com; rel=preconnect
>   Link: https://example.com/next-page.html; rel=prerender;
>   Link: https://example.com/logo-hires.jpg; rel=prefetch; as=image;

## What went wrong

Dev tools shows the `Link` header in the initial request:

[image: Link header]

I see the connection to mac9416.com established after the 200, immediately before the resource is downloaded.

I expected to see the connection established immediately after the 302, or simply missing from the timeline.

[image: Connection portion of dev tools network timeline]

I tested using Chrome 73. The [WebPageTest waterfall](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190328_5A_bd69fb24feae1627742d203b9bb16343/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1) looks almost identical.

**Note:** I'm interested in server-push solutions, but for now the site in question runs HTTP1.1.

## The question

Am I attempting something that isn't even supported? Must resource hint headers be served on non-redirect responses only?

[The "Anonymizing redirect" section of the resource hint working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#anonymizing-redirect-preconnect) leads me to believe it's meant to help in exactly my type of situation. But maybe I'm misreading.

> Many sites rely on redirect services for analytics, malware protection, and to anonymize the referrer before sending the user to the final destination. Because the destination is known ahead of time, a preconnect hint can be used to initiate the connection handshake with the destination origin (without revealing any private information) in parallel with the processing of the redirect - this masks the redirect latency and reduces navigation time to final destination.

Comment: All seems a bit vague. Which resource hint did you use? Which browser? And can you give the full waterfall diagram? Ideally the public website and the webpagetest results for this. I don’t think the browsers have formally stated whether they accept these on redirects so testing would be the best way to confirm.

Comment: @BarryPollard fair points. 1) preconnect, 2) Chrome 73, and 3) I'll try to set up an example on my personal site and post WPT results this evening.

Comment: @BarryPollard updated with a demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I checked out your experiment (thanks for knocking that up!) and couldn't see anything wrong with it. I also repeated it myself on my own server and can confirm your findings: none of the major browsers seem to support resource hints across page redirects.

As to the paragraph from the draft spec you point out, I can think of two explanations:

1. This **is** a potential use case and the browsers are just not supporting it (yet).
2. This wording is more intended for resources on the current page that have to go through a redirect first. So if for example the current page (index.html) loads `www.example.com/latest/framework.js` and that redirects to `cdn.example.com/latest/framework.js` to actually load this resource. It's notable that only prefetch and prerender explicitly note they are meant for the "next navigation" (though I tried those two out of interest and they also don't work for the redirect scenario).

Either way I agree it could be clearer. I was going to suggest opening an issue on Github but see [you already did that](https://github.com/w3c/resource-hints/issues/87)! Hopefully the spec authors can confirm this.

Incidentally I tried with a JavaScript redirect instead of a 301/302 and it worked in Chrome for both HTTP link header and HTML link instructions for preconnect - suggesting again that only 200 responses are looked at for resource hints.
[image: Resource hint on Javascript redirect]

An interesting question you raised! Not sure if off topic for StackOverflow but certainly piqued my interest...

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, especially for trying out the JavaScript alternative! That route is a little trickier for the _actual_ site I want to implement this on. So hopefully browsers implement hints for 301/302s soon.

Comment: NP. JavaScript redirects are bad and shoudn't be used IMHO so not advocating them. More looked out of interest and to confirm suspicions.

Comment: Just offhand, what are the downsides to JS redirects? I agree they feel icky, just wondering what the concrete problems are.

Comment: Off the top if my head: 1) Requires Javascript to be enabled, 2) not good for SEO, 3) It says the page is loaded (200) when it's not. Probably more a niggle for OCD weirdos like me but might also break other tools 4) it's slower as requires the JavaScript to be executed 5) if redirect is based on user input then could be security issues. Basically it boils down to the fact that HTTP has a better method for this and always has had (HTTP/0.9 aside) and the JavaScript method is a hack (like a lot of JavaScript - yes I went there!!) :-)

Comment: I suspect the JS example works as the browser has to instantiate a document, whereas in the case of the location header the browser just redirects early

Looking at a Chrome net-log for @MichaelCrenshaw test case, Chrome doesn't even try to make the connection to the CSS domain